# NSNotificationCenter Post to nil -> crash

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uikit, nsnotification

My TableViewCell register for Notifications. But i can't unregister because i don't know when. 
I tried to subclass NSNotificationCenter but i didn't tried it the right way.

Some Ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You need to give us a little more detail about the nature of your notification. When do you register, when do you want to deregister? Is dealloc feasible?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `UITableViewCell` rarely gets `dealloc`'ed

Usually what you want is to call `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]` in your subclass' `prepareForReuse` method. (Be sure to call `[super prepareForReuse];` in your implementation!)

Comment: BTW, I agree with @Till's comment that you're probably in the weeds if you're doing this and may want to consider refactoring so that this is handled in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

A classic approach would registering your notifications within a `UIViewController` derived class in `viewDidLoad` and unregistering in `viewDidUnload`.

For a `UIView` derived class, you should really think twice if you are going the right way (mixing display-logic- with business-logic-code). However, you could register in `initWithFrame` and unregister on `dealloc`.

Since `UITableViewCell` is `UIView` derived, the right places could be registering in  `initWithStyle` and unregistering in `dealloc` as well (in case you are not reusing your cells).

Comment: my tableviewcell register on start of an download. i want to deregister if download is finished (this already works) and if the cell scrolls out of the visible screen. but i didn't get an information about exiting the screen.

Comment: No you won't get that since the cell will be reused. This is a great example of an incorrect approach. Don't do this in the view but in its controller. Redo the entire approach and use the controller, not the view itself for business logic.

Comment: but if the NotificationCenter would check if the observer would be nil everything would be fine. i can't track downloads and notifications from the controller to the cell with a hundred cells to track.

Comment: @JeanetteMüller right, but that is not the way this should be tackled. The cell will be reused, hence it will not be NIL. You could either override prepareForReuse or add a custom method that is called whenever you start using a cell that simply unregisters it (just in case).